# VBA ADO recordset_Edited to include all of the code

Tags: excel, vba, ado

I have this recordset that selects data from open master sheet with "PMWEB_BOA_Projects" based on users name and brings their data from the open master sheet over to the "Assigned Projects - Retail" sheet. My problem is that, my team does not want to have to go enter their folder directory address into the "rng" location I have so that the ADO recordset knows where to look for the workbook in. How can I bypass having to put a folder directory without them having to save the workbook and still just use the macros?

```vb
Sub GetQueryResults2(SQLV6Retail As String)

'===============================
'This is for V6 data tab bringing data from retail workbook report

    Dim myfilespath As String
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng As String
    Dim LO As ListObject
    
  Set LO = Worksheets("Assigned projects - RETAIL").ListObjects("Assigned")
        
        LO.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set ws2 = Workbooks("PMWEB_BOA_Projects.xlsm").Sheets("Instructions")
rng = ws2.Range("F17").Value

myfilepath = ThisWorkbook.Path


'This one is for V6 data tab
cn.Mode = adModeRead
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & rng & "\PMWEB_BOA_Projects.xlsm;" & _
    "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';"


cn.Open

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.ActiveConnection = cn
rs.Source = SQLV6Retail


rs.Open


Set ws = Workbooks("PMWEB_BOA_Projects.xlsm").Sheets("Assigned Projects - RETAIL")

ws.Activate
ws.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
cn.Close


End Sub

Private Sub filterboa_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim SQLV6Retail As String
    Dim BOARetail As String
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim SQLV6CORP As String
    
    'Worksheets("Assigned Projects").unprotect Password:="joshy"
    'save to network drive
     'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
'Filename:=rng & "PMWEB_BOA_Projects"

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    With wb1.Sheets("Assigned projects - CORP")
    
    Last_row = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    End With

    'Call copyassignedprojects
    
    wb1.Sheets("Assigned projects - Retail").Activate
    wb1.Sheets("Assigned projects - Retail").Range("A2:AK2" & Last_row).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    BOARetail = ListBox1.Value
    
    SQLV6Retail = "Select [Project Number], [Project Name], [Status], [15_Actual], [Project Manager], [Project Coordinator or BOA], [JPMC Budget], [JPMC Commitments], [JPMC Actuals], [SP Budget], " & _
    "[SP Commitments], [SP Actuals], [Total Budget], [Total Commitments], [Total Actuals], " & _
    "[09B_Construction Release_OVP: 28 Constr Release Notif], " & _
    "[13_Substantial Completion_OVP: 40 Substantial Compl], [15_Closeout_OVP: 45 Closeout], " & _
    "[15A_Punchlist Complete_OVP: 44 Punchlist Complete]" & _
    "From [V6 data$] WHERE [Project Coordinator or BOA] = '" & BOARetail & "'  "
    
    'run the query with the sql string
    GetQueryResults2 SQLV6Retail
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code - no one can copy/paste the code when it's like that.

Comment: Its not letting me copy and paste:

Comment: This is now updated to show the code.

Comment: Where is `rng` used in the code ?

Comment: "Data Source=" & rng & "\PMWEB_BOA_Projects.xlsm;" & _

Comment: Im playing with the data source to try to capture the activeworkbook instead. but thats where rng is used to make the code work the way its supposed to

Comment: Where is the code located, is it in `Workbooks("PMWEB_BOA_Projects.xlsm")` ?

Comment: Yes, it is in that workbook. And it is the only workbook needed open

Comment: Is this a shared workbook opened from a shared location? If not then where is it opened from?

Comment: If you need a general solution then you're going to need to tell us more about for example where each user has this workbook saved.  We have no idea how things are arranged in your workplace...

Comment: The workbook would be downloaded from sharepoint which all employees would download the workbook and open it up to select their projects and bring into the main sheet within workbook

Comment: Would they download the workbook, or just open it directly from sharePoint?  If they're downloading it then `ThisWorkbook.Path` would give you the location of the locally-saved file (likely in the users' "Downloads" folder)  If that's not working then you'd need to tell us exactly what happens when it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `"Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

   Const SQLV6Retail = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]" ' test
    
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, sConn As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim LO As ListObject, n As Long
   
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'Workbooks("PMWEB_BOA_Projects.xlsm")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Assigned projects - RETAIL")
    Set LO = ws.ListObjects("Assigned")
    LO.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        
    sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';"
    'Debug.Print sConn
    
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    With cn
        .Mode = adModeRead 'This one is for V6 data tab
        .ConnectionString = sConn
        .Open
    End With
    
    ws.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset cn.Execute(SQLV6Retail)
    cn.Close
    MsgBox "Done", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, the answer did not work. The new code is what works. However, in the "rng" cell, I need enter the directory of where to find the workbook. If i remove the rng calue then the error pops up stating it cannot be found. I need others to be able download this workbook to their own computers and beable to import their proejcts from that listbox value

Comment: @JCARD_77 How does `rng` differ from `Thisworkbook.Path` ?